# Why was ReplicaSet introduced in Kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes, replicaset

I understand the difference between ReplicaSet and ReplicationController, of former being Set based and the latter Equality based. What I want to know is why was a newer implementation (Read ReplicaSet) introduced when the older ReplicationController achieves the same functionality.

Comment: in this post you can find a good comparison
[What is the difference between ReplicaSet and ReplicationController?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41190819/5571750)

Comment: Thanks for the share, however, I had viewed that particular thread before too. That answers the difference between RC and RS but I intend to know why was RS introduced while functionality wise ReplicationController achieves the same.

Answer (score 1):

`ReplicaSet` is usually not standalone, these are owned by `Deployment`. A single `Deployment` can have many `ReplicaSet`s in its life cycle as new `Version` deployment added one more `ReplicaSet`.

`Deployment` allows us to rollback to previous stable releases if required.

Answer (score 1):

Replicasets is updated version of Replication controller

In Replication controller there equality-based selectors

In Replicasets there is set-based selectors

Replicasets also work with deployment so when you do simple deployment in kubernetes replicasets automatically generated and managed.so deployment `owned` replicasets.

Answer (score 1):

I think this can be summed up to the 3 points below.

1 ) ReplicaSet is a replacement for the Replica controller and supports richer expressions for the label selector. You can choose between four values of operators `In, NotIn, Exists, DoesNotExist` - see [Set-based requirement](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/labels/#set-based-requirement).

2 ) There is a small differnece in the syntax - ReplicaSet which contains `matchLabels` field under the selector:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: ReplicaSet
metadata:
  name: nginx
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels: #<-- This was added
      tier: nginx
```

3 ) When you see Replica Controller is mentioned in one the docs or other tutorials - refer to it as ReplicaSet AND consider using Deployment instead.