# Can't delete a pod added trough Kubernetes Dashboard

Tags: kubernetes, microk8s

I added a pod through Kubernetes Dashboard. I used Create new resource and I created a pod from input.

I then tried to delete it with:

```
kubectl delete -n default pod pod-name-0
```

It deletes it, but gets redeployed. As I understand, I should delete it's deployment first. So to list deployments, I used

```
kubectl get deployments
```

But it's not there. How do I permanently delete a pod?

Comment: You can check the output of `kubectl get all` this should display all (usual) workloads. My guess is that something like a ReplicaSet was created together with your pod. E.g a ReplicaSet would recreate missing workloads.

Comment: I created a StatefulSet, so I had to delete that. Thanks, your command helped.

Answer (score 2):

The pods are maintained by a ReplicationController and they are automatically replaced if they fail, are deleted, or are terminated, you should check

```
kubectl describe pods POD_NAME
kubectl describe replicationcontrollers/REPLICATION_CONTROLLER_NAME
```

Alternatively you can check the ReplicaSet `kubectl get rs`

Afterwards you can: `kubectl edit rs REPLICASET_NAME` and change the replicas count up or down as you desire.

Nice [explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36220388/what-is-the-difference-between-replicaset-and-replicationcontroller) regarding ReplicaSet vs ReplicationController